# unable to create a uber jar with all resources included

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-resources-plugin, uberjar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>JavaExeDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JavaExeDemo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>application/application.css</resource>
                                    <file>/testProject/src/main/java/application/application.css</file>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <outputDirectory>testProject/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>testProject/src/main/resources/ui/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>testProject/src/main/java/com/xyz/internal/installer</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>testProject/src/main/java/application</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
</project>
```

I am new to Maven and have been trying to create an uber jar for my application. I have been able to include the *application.css* mentioned in the include transformer (only when the resources tag is 'not' used) however I have a few resources scattered across the project with paths as below:

1. /src/main/resources/ui/
2. /src/main/java/com/xyz/internal/installer

I have tried to include them as resources in the code, however the images inside 
`/src/main/resources/ui/` are included but the otherlocation are not. Also when i do not use resources tag the 'application.css' is included in the jar, otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml looks incorrect. You have [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) mixed with maven shade plugin configuration.

You should configure your pom like below,

```
   <build>       
    <resources>         
        <resource>        
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ui/</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/xyz/internal/installer/</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/application</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!... 0ther stuff like dependencies...... >
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                        <resource>application/application.css</resource>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/application/application.css</file>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

Few points,

1. I have used ${project.basedir} instead of testproject/src/... this is a best practice and you should not hard code your project name. Similarly use ${project.build.directory} for target directory. See [this](https://github.com/cko/predefined_maven_properties/blob/master/README.md).
2. If you want to copy your resources specified in resource filter to a specific location, you have to use [copy resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).
3. [include empty directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html#includeEmptyDirs) is one of the configuration of copy resource plugin